# POST to first row of database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, post, database-design

**EDIT: this was solved - please see the comments**

I’ve got a spreadsheet table built on the front end of my website. Users want the ability to click an ‘Add row’ button to add a new blank row to the first row of this spreadsheet.

I’m trying to think of how to accomplish this as opposed to adding a row to the end of the table, which is easy since my ID `primary key` column automatically increments via my `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` settings.

But how do you handle this situation when you need to add a new row to the beginning of a database table? When I place a new row to the database, it should have the ID of 1, and every other ID below that row should increase by 1 to compensate. This is what I’m currently trying to accomplish – but Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is not doing this for me. The `POST` request of my new row goes through without error, but never shows up in my database nor on page refresh of my front end spreadsheet.

Currently, when my New Row button is clicked, the `addRow` event fires which looks like this:

```
  addRow(args) {
        const self = this;
        var sheet = self.spread.getActiveSheet();
        changedSheet.addRows(0, 1);
        Var apiURL = "api/myTable";

            var jsonObject = {
                ID: 1
            };

            for ( var i=1; i<this.spreadColumns.length; i++) {
                jsonObject[this.spreadColumns[i]] = changedSheet.getValue(args.row, i);
               // WHEN FOR LOOP FINISHED, SUBMIT POST REQUEST
                if (this.spreadColumns.length - 1 === i) {
                    this.databaseServoce.post(apiURL, jsonObject);
                }
            }
  }
```

Help me Jon Skeet – you’re my only hope.

Comment: The problem is the misconception that a database table has an order. By definition it is an unordered set. Order only has meaning when querying the table. That means if you want to specify an order other than order rows are inserted you need to use your own column for this. Then it becomes trivial to insert a row "before another one". You simply update all the rows after the position of the new one and insert the new row.

Comment: `and every other ID below that row should increase by 1 to compensate` could be problematic when you have a lot of data in the data and is not a good practice. Can't you simply `display` your data ordered descending? so when they add a new row it will show as first but id will be +1 the last one

Comment: Thank you both - you are correct. With this in mind, I'm still unable to get my `POST` to work when creating a new row. I believe it's because my primary key column (`ID`) cannot accept null values - but I'm sending null values for my new blank row on the front end. I thought perhaps the database would automatically include the ID field on the backend regardless since it's set to auto-increment. But apparently not. Struggling to find a way to POST an empty row to a database successfully. Or at least, how to post a new iteration of my Primary Key on this new row, programatically from front end.

Comment: Ahh - I see. In my case, I needed to call the .subscribe() method (I'm using `Angular`) after my POST. Without this, I wasn't getting any errors but my POST wasn't populating the database. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49205778/6647188

On that note, if either of you want, feel free to post your comments above as an answer and I'll mark it as Accepted. Thanks so much for your help with my initial question.